# How to loop through multiple sections in a table view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on a project which shows multiple rows with three sections in a tableview. If the user taps on the individual row in a section, that row color should be sent to DetailVC. Currently I am sending one section of colors to DetailVC by using a `switch` statement. Now I want to send the remaining section colors to DetailVC.

Here is my code. I pretty much tried, but it didn't work for me. I know that I have to change code in the `switch` statement.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cellID = "Cell"

    let twoDimensionalArray = [
                                ["Blue","Green","Red"],
                                ["Orange","Purple"],
                                ["Brown","Yellow"]
                              ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 44.0
    }

    // Mark:- Tableview datasource methods
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return twoDimensionalArray.count
    }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Header"
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        return label
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return twoDimensionalArray[section].count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.imageview.image = UIImage(named : twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = self.storyboard? .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2") as! DetailViewController

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            vc.passedImage = UIImage(named : "Blue")!
           self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break
        case 1:
            vc.passedImage = UIImage(named : "Green")!
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break
        case 2:
            vc.passedImage = UIImage(named : "Red")!
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break
        default :
            vc.passedImage = UIImage(named : "Blue")!
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is that the selected row color in a section is to be shown in DetailVC. It is showing the colors only in the one section, but not in all the sections in a tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a multidimensional array you can access it using the `indexPath` `section` and `row` properties to get the color `String` for that `indexPath`. Then you can create your `UIImage` and set it on your detail view controller.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = self.storyboard? .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2") as! DetailViewController
        let color = twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        vc.passedImage = UIImage(named : color)!
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```